Error to restClient & HttpWebRequest- The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
In my ASP.NET MVC project (.Net Framework 4.7.2), I am consuming as API which is hosted on another server developed by vendor. Whenever I tried to hit same API through code, I am getting an error response from an API - "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.". But when I hit same same API through SOAP UI from server (Windows 2019) where my code is deployed, it provide proper response without error.
Refer my below code to get more idea
        try
        {
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + XXXXXXX);
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "XXXXXXXX");
            
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                   | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            return (response.Content);
      }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

New UPDATE:
I developed a new code with HttpWebRequest still I am getting same response. For more info, please refer my new code below.
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
            //                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
            //                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
            //                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            //webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(ConfigVariables.ProxyIP, ConfigVariables.ProxyPort);
            webRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headervalue))
            {
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + headervalue);
            }

            System.IO.StreamWriter requestWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
            requestWriter.Write(postString);
            requestWriter.Close();
            System.IO.StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

            responseReader.Close();
            webRequest.GetResponse().Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

New Update 2
I tried with HttpClient.Still same issue. Refer code of HttpClient which I devloped.
        try
        {
            using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url
                //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", headervalue);
                //Sending request to web api
                System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, url);
                //Receiving  response from web api
                System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api
                    result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

All Above code worl perfectly fine on LOCAL MACHINE but not on deployed server.  WHAT AM I MISSING??
Also refer API Report from Sslabs.com -


Post the actual full exception text. There may be an inner exception that explains what's wrong. Also remove the hard-coded attempts to set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol. This doesn't enable TLS 1.2, it prevents the application from using TLS 1.3 or better, while trying to re-enable obsolete algorithms. That won't work though. TLS is provided by the OS itself, not .NET.

In fact, the original code  enables the obsolete algorithms only to disable them again and set TLS1.2 using a hack that was only needed in 4.0. All this code seems to be copy-pasta, trying to fix the real problem at random. This won't fix anything, it will only create more problems.

when I hit ... from server (Windows 2019) .. without error. so there's no error. Are you using an obsolete Windows version for development? All supported Windows versions (ie 10 and later) support TLS 1.2 out of the box. Older versions require patching to enable it. Trying to hard-code the setting in .NET won't do anything because the actual OS support is missing. Since 4.6.2, the best available TLS version is used automatically.

@PanagiotisKanavos: I developed new code with HttpClient but still same issue. As you suggested, I logged stacktrace & InnerExcpetion. Please refer the same above in question  in New Update 2.
